# Example of apply other than + in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

If 'apply' applies the given function to all elements of list, why following does not work:

```
> (apply println (list "a" "b" "c"))
. . println: contract violation
  expected: output-port?
  given: "b"
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
>
```

The example given in both https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html and https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html relate to add (+) function. Could someone provide other examples of apply and explain how it really works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like `(apply + (list 1 2 3 4))` is equivalent to `(+ 1 2 3 4)`, `(apply println (list "a" "b" "c"))` is equivalent to `(println "a" "b" "c")`. However that's not a valid use of `println`. As the error message suggests, the second argument should be an output port, not a string.

To correctly call `println` using `apply`, you must supply a valid argument list, such as:

```
(apply println (list "a"))
;; or
(apply println (list "a" (current-output-port))
```

Here's some examples of using `apply` with functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments and will thus always work regardless of the length of the list:

```
(apply * (list 1 2 3 4))    ; 24
(apply list (list 1 2 3 4)) ; (list 1 2 3 4) ¹
(apply set (list 1 2 3 4))  ; (set 1 2 3 4)
```

---

¹ Well, you wouldn't really use `apply` with `list` as that just gives you back the same list (or rather a copy of it), but you can.

Comment: Can you provide an example of apply for any fn other than + ?

Comment: I found that (apply or (list #f #f #t)) does not work. Error is " or: bad syntax in: or".  Why is that so? 'Or' is also a function like '+' which can take multiple arguments.

Comment: @rnso `or` isn't a function, it's a syntactic form to allow short circuiting (that is `(or #t (f 42))` is not going to call `(f 42)` because it stops after the first true condition). The downside of this is that you can't pass it as an argument to functions like `apply` or `foldl`.

Comment: Why 'and' does not work with apply, even if it must be evaluating all its arguments?

Comment: @rnso `and` short-circuits, too - just on false rather than true values (i.e. if any argument is false, the end result will also be false without evaluating any subsequent arguments).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply a procedure eg. `(proc a b c)` but the arguments are supplied in a list. You could do `(proc (car l) (cadr l) (caddr l))` but you can also just do `(apply proc l)`. If you have additional arguments you want in front you can even do `(apply proc 5 l)` and it is the same as `(proc 5 (car l) (cadr l) (caddr l))`. `apply` takes any number of arguments but the very last needs to be a list of the final arguments.

It's important to understand that `apply` is not a fold. If you have a procedure that takes exactly one argument then you can apply that with a list of exactly one element or else the procedure will fail..

```
(cons 1 2)           ; ==> (1 . 2)
(apply cons '(1 2))  ; ==> (1 . 2)

(cons 1 2 3)         ; ==> ERROR cons: arity mismatch
(apply cons '(1 2 3)); ==> ERROR cons: arity mismatch
```

`apply` is the opposite of a rest argument:

```
(define (proc arg1 . argn)
  (apply list arg1 argn)) 

(proc 1 2 3 4) ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

It is **not a fold**

```
;; a two arity add
(define (add a b)
  (+ a b))

(apply add '(1 2))     ; ==> 3
(apply add '(1 2 3))   ; ==> ERROR add: arity mismatch

;; foldl is a fold
(foldl add 0 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 6
```